# Counting points on Hessenberg varieties over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, finite-fields, weyl-group

Let $G$ be an connected reductive group over finite field $k$. I will assume that $\text{char}(k)$ is very good for $G$ (or even larger, if preferred). Let $B\subset G$ be a Borel subgroup defined over $k$. Let $\mathfrak{h}\subset\text{Lie }G$ be a subspace such that $\mathfrak{h}\supset\text{Lie }B$ and $\text{Ad}(B)\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{h}$. Take any regular semisimple $X\in(\text{Lie }G)(k)$. Consider

$$\mathcal{H}_{X,\mathfrak{h}}=\{g\in B\backslash G\,|\,\text{Ad}(g)X\in\mathfrak{h}\}.$$

Over $\bar{k}$, $\mathcal{H}_{X,\mathfrak{h}}$ has a stratification by affine spaces, given by first conjugate $X$ into a maximal torus $T\subset B$, then intersect $\mathcal{H}_{X,\mathfrak{h}}$ with the Schubert cells $B\backslash BwB$ for $w\in N_G(T)/T$. However this doesn't work over $k$ if $X$ does not centralize a maximal split torus.

**Question: Any method to count $\mathcal{H}_{X,\mathfrak{h}}(k)$?**

A naive try of mine was to just look at the Frobenius action on "Schubert cells", but it seems that Frobenius can send a Schubert cell to a "non-Schubert cell," i.e. to some cell that is not a Schubert cell from any pair of $(B^*,T^*)$.

The motivation is that such counting problems simply appear if one wants to count points on affine Springer fibers, or more generally, compute $p$-adic orbital integral.